# Japa of 111 beads in Kaliyuga​?

Tags: kali-yuga, japa, japamala

Count of beads according to Yuga.

111 for Kaliyuga ?

In Hinduism there is 1 mala of 108 beads.

Is it true that 108 beads mala is for Dvapara Yuga while 111 beads mala is for Kaliyuga ?

Would like to know in Hinduism, are number of beads in one mala decided
according to Yuga; Treta , Dvapara and Kali ?

On Wikipedia, Prayer Beads page,

According to Vedic scriptures 103 beads were used during Treta Yuga, 108 beads during Dvapara Yuga, and 111 beads in Kali Yuga.

[Wikipedia Prayer Beads](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_beads&hl=en-IN)

[image: screenshot of prayer beads page]

Comment: No, where did u learn this? There's nothing like that..

Comment: Only rule i know about yUga and japa is in Kali Chaturguna japa (four times) is to be done whle purashcharana (but this rule does not apply for all mantras)..

Comment: Read on Wikipedia, trying to find the page

Comment: @Christopher please share the link where you read it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_beads#Hinduism 3rd paragraph on that section. BTW also similar say just down on buddhism section **In Tibetan Buddhism, often larger malas are used; for example, malas of 111 beads** . Never heard something like 111 beads nor 103

Comment: First, the WIkipedia article referenced says 'citation needed'. so somebody just put down some anecdotal story they heard without reference. Never heard of 111. Always 108.